# running cygwin commands in a windows bat file

Tags: linux, batch-file, cygwin

am trying to run the cygwin command in a windows batch file, 
however, the cygwin command only reaches to the cygwin interactive promt.

### my code is as follows in the windows bat file

```
@echo off

C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin

bash --login -i
split -l 1 test.txt
logoff
exit
```

it only reaches to the command interface for cygwin/linux 
[command prompt reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbXP9.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is, because you've not fully explained it, but I assume that you've not got a file `xaa` after this script finishes. Is there a file named `text.txt` residing in `C:\cygwin\bin`? or does the login via `bash` automatically change the current working directory to another one? Or are you expecting that the commands which follow `bash …` are all executed within `bash`, despite those lines being invoked under `cmd`?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `bash --login -i`, you enter in an interactive bash shell.

What you need is :

```
bash -c "cd /path/to/your-test-txt; split -l 1 test.txt"
```